# Burninate [differences]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

What it says on the tin. With 106 questions, the [differences](/questions/tagged/differences) tag is described solely as a tag that should not be used.

[image]

Comment: someone should search inside tag wikis of _all_ tags, I bet there are many more (I would search for `(do not/don't)+use, meta, blacklist`).

Comment: +1 this image is cool..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was fun.

P.S. When you're mass retagging, try to fix some of the minor things that are easy to notice as well, such as small formatting errors and removing "thanks" etc from the end of the post. :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Please tell me you looked for more than just minor formatting errors, that you voted to close/flagged crap questions....

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas I went back through my history and CV'd a couple that were obvious NARQs, but most of them are outside my area of expertise. I wouldn't be able to tell a good question from a bad one.