# Burninate and blacklist [difference]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The fight with [differences] was successfull: [Burninate [differences]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161448/burninate-differences)

But the hydra is reborn.

Please burninate [difference](/questions/tagged/difference). It's a pure meta-tag and a clone of [differences]. Additional blacklisting would prevent resurecting as [difference-between] or similar.

Comment: nuke it, nuke it now.... then erase it from existence!

Comment: I suggest [tag:what-is-the-difference], [tag:difference-description] and [tag:no-really-how-are-they-different].